# Get the Primary Key of a new Entry

Tags: c#, .net, database, ms-access, primary-key

I have a number of child tables that have a foreign key to a parent table.

How do I add an entry in the parent table and get the primary key of that entry, so that I can then enter rows in the child tables that point to the entry in the parent table?

I'm doing this in a MS Access Database from a C# application.

Comment: Already answered (where the number of referencing tables is one). See: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151905/best-way-to-make-double-insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151905/best-way-to-make-double-insert "Best way to make double insert")

Comment: You're not using an Access database, but a Jet database. Access is an application development platform, while Jet is the database engine for the data store that the default in Access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Access 2000 or later does support the @@IDENTITY property to retrieve the value of an Autonumber field after an INSERT. ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0(VS.71).aspx))

Edit: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0.aspx) is the link to a similar article for .NET 3.5

Comment: -1 for referencing outdated information. The .NET 3.5 section makes not mention of this.

Comment: Leppie, writting the updated information would have been great!!

Comment: Added a 3.5 link, which is available on the originally linked page.

Answer (score 4):

[Getting the identity of the most recently added record](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article.aspx?ArticleID=54)

Answer (score 3):

Try looking into the global variables that will give you the identity value. In SQL Server it is:

SELECT @@identity

Also look into the Scope_Identity() function

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to SELECT @@IDENTITY even though you will have to use a second query to do so. I don't think MS Access will allow it to be combined into one query.